# I am failing to put identity on an exisiting column of a Table

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

```
Alter Table contacts
Alter column cont_id int identity(1,1) NOT NULL
Go
```

I am failing to insert identity  on an exisiting Table

Comment: Is there an error message involved? Might you be willing to share it? Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have duplicates for the identity column. I advise you to get rid of duplicates and if the command still fails to execute, then create a new table, migrate all the data there, clear the table, issue the command and migrate the data back. If you already have another identity, that might also be an issue.